# Build native Quarkus image under Java 16?

Tags: quarkus, graalvm-native-image, java-16

Is it possible to build the native Quarkus image under Java 16? Didn't find any instructions how to do it.

Somehow, it should be possible to do it because Oracle released GraalVM support for Java 16  (https://www.graalvm.org/release-notes/21_1/)

Answer (score 2):

It should be possible (all you need to do is install the appropriate GraalVM version or the quay.io/quarkus/ubi-quarkus-native-image:21.1.0-java16 docker image) , but as of this time it is not part of our CI so your mileage may vary.

Comment: If you want to use the Docker image, you can simply use: `./mvw clean install -Dnative -Dquarkus.native.container-build=true -Dquarkus.native.builder-image=quay.io/quarkus/ubi-quarkus-native-image:21.1.0-java16`.

Comment: tried to build app with the following command `./gradlew build -Dquarkus.package.type=native -Dquarkus.native.container-build=true -Dquarkus.native.native-image-xmx=4G -Dquarkus.native.builder-image=quay.io/quarkus/ubi-quarkus-native-image:21.1.0-java16 -x test`. Got the error `Could not find target method: private void io.quarkus.runtime.graal.MappedByteBufferReplacement.force0(java.io.FileDescriptor,long,long)`. Mb it is still early to use Java 16